# bootstrap блок внутри container

Tags: bootstrap

На странице у меня есть блок `container` с шириной `1200px`.

Нужно внутри этого блока, другой блок `div` растянуть на всю ширину монитора. Если выставить `width: 100%`, соответственно будет на ширину `container`.
как это можно сделать? без `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 1):

Если без абсолюта, то только так (вынести в другой контейнер):

```
<div class="container"> ... </div>
<div class="container-fluid"> <div > тут Ваш блок </div> </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

тут в принципе не нужен container-fluid.

```
<div class="container"> ... </div>
<div class="full-width-block" style="width: 100%;">
  Тут блок на всю ширину экрана 
  <div class="container"> 
      Тут обычный контейнер 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: в вопросе же указано, что уже есть нужный контейнер

Comment: так я и написал что надо вынести его за пределы контейнера -> растянуть на всю ширину -> внутри вставить свой контейнер (если требуется)

Comment: а он написал, что надо внутри контейнера.